# Inserting all the results of a query into table

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I need to do something which is a logical equivalent of the following

```
Insert into MainTable values(100, SELECT DISTINCT(Value) from RefTable where Keyval = 1);
```

I implemented it using a temporary table and was wondering if there is a more straightforward solution

**Tables:**

```
create table MainTable
(
    Id          bigint  NOT NULL,
    Value       bigint  NOT NULL,
    Flag        bit NULL,

    primary key (Id, Value));


create table RefTable
(
        Keyval      bigint  NOT NULL,
        Value       bigint  NOT NULL,
);
```

**RefTable values:**

```
1 5
1 6
1 6
1 7
2 6
2 7
```

**MainTable values after insertion:**

```
100 5
100 6
100 7
```

**My solution:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT(Value)
        INTO #Temp
        FROM RefTable 
        where Keyval = 1

    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #Temp)
    BEGIN
        Select Top 1 @value= Value From #Temp
        INSERT INTO MainTable 
        VALUES(100, @value);
        Delete #Temp Where Keyval = 1
    END

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#Temp', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE tempdb.dbo.#Temp
```

Comment: `distinct` is ***not*** a function. Using `(...)` around the column is not necessary, useless and does nothing. You wouldn't write `select (value)` would you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do a distinct and insert the values

```
insert into MainTable
(Id,Value)
select distinct 100,  value from RefTable
where id =1
```